# How to change the default text in dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm having trouble changing the default text of my dropzone uploader. Despite the fact that I've initialized it like this, it's still rendering the default text:

```
Dropzone.options.imgUpload = {
    paramName: "file", // Must match the name of the HttpPostedFileBase argument that the Upload action expects.
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drag your image here",
    acceptedFiles: "image/*" // Accept images only
};
```

Also tried changing the dictDefaultMessage set in dropzone.js, but with no luck :(
By the way; am I supposed to use both or remove one of them?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved this by including the `basic.css` file alone. This does not render the sprites and you have full control of styling inside the dropzone (It just gives jo a basic skeleton to improve upon). When doing this, `dictDefaultMessage` is displayed.

Comment: The css can be found here -  [https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/tree/master/downloads](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/tree/master/downloads)

Answer (score 4):

This is based on the documentation of dropzone.js ([enter link description here](http://www.dropzonejs.com/))

*(without styles)*
http://jsfiddle.net/44pnR/1/

**HTML**

```
<form action="/file-upload"
      class="dropzone"
      id="img-upload"></form>
```

**JS**

```
/*"imgUpload" is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID*/
Dropzone.options.imgUpload  = {
    paramName: "file", // Must match the name of the HttpPostedFileBase argument that the Upload action expects.
    dictDefaultMessage: "custom message",
    acceptedFiles: "image/*" // Accept images only
};
```

Comment: Ok, this is strange. Cannot seem to change the text. I've even done a "Find All" in my entire solution and cannot seem to find the text that is currently set anywhere. When searching further, I found a Spritemap that contains the text. How come it doesn't change this to my custom text? :(

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me is to add:

`<div class="dz-message" data-dz-message><span>Drag your image here!</span></div>`

into my HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding anything with class as "dz-message" will replace the original text.